# Put more than one child JAXBElement into parent JAXBElement

Tags: java, jaxb

The following code works:

```
private List<Object> custom;

@XmlAnyElement
public List<Object> getCustom() {
    if (custom == null) {
        custom = new ArrayList<>();

        final JAXBElement<String> lv2elem =
            new JAXBElement<String>(new QName("lv2"), String.class, "val1");

        final JAXBElement lv1elem =
            new JAXBElement(new QName("lv1"), JAXBElement.class, lv2elem);
        custom.add(lv1elem);
    }
    return custom;
}
```

When marshaling the object it produces the following XML:

```
<xml>
    <lv1>
        <lv2>val1</lv2>
    </lv1>
</xml>
```

**How to make it produce more than one `lv2` element?** The desired output:

```
<xml>
    <lv1>
        <lv2>val1</lv2>
        <lv2>val2</lv2>
    </lv1>
</xml>
```

In the end I want to create a deep XML structure with dynamic tags.

I tried to pass different `declaredType` and `value` to the constructor of `lv1elem`, without luck:

```
// class [Ljavax.xml.bind.JAXBElement; nor any of its super class is known to this context.
lv1elem = new JAXBElement(new QName("lv1"), JAXBElement.class, new JAXBElement[] { lv2elem });

// [Ljavax.xml.bind.JAXBElement; is not known to this context
lv1elem = new JAXBElement(new QName("lv1"), JAXBElement[].class, new JAXBElement[] { lv2elem });

// class java.util.Arrays$ArrayList nor any of its super class is known to this context.
lv1elem = new JAXBElement(new QName("lv1"), JAXBElement.class, Arrays.asList(new JAXBElement[] { lv2elem } ));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a workaround by using an intermediate java bean `Recurs` having a property of type `List<Object>`. I still have to wrap `Recurs` with `JAXBElement` to change the tag name from default `<recurs>` to the desired one: `<lv1>` . The list inside `Recurs` can contain one or more `JAXBElement` including other `JAXBElement<Recurs>` or some other type known to JAXB context.

```
public class Recurs {

    private List<Object> custom;

    @XmlAnyElement
    public List<Object> getCustom() {
        if (custom == null) {
            custom = new ArrayList<>();
        }
        return custom;
    }

    public void setCustom(List<Object> custom) {
        this.custom = custom;
    }
}


@XmlRootElement
@XmlSeeAlso({ Recurs.class }) // !!! This is important
public class Xml {
    private List<Object> custom;

    @XmlAnyElement
    public List<Object> getCustom() {
        if (custom == null) {
            custom = new ArrayList<>();

            JAXBElement<String> lv2elem;
            Recurs recurs = new Recurs();
            for (int i = 1; i <= 2; i++) {
                lv2elem = new JAXBElement<String>(new QName("lv2"), String.class, "val" + i);
                recurs.getCustom().add(lv2elem);
            }
            JAXBElement lv1elem = new JAXBElement(new QName("lv1"), Recurs.class, recurs);
            custom.add(lv1elem);
        }
        return custom;
    }

}
```